# Call a non-global variable from a function?

Tags: php, function, variables, joomla, global

During the development of a Joomla! plugin, I ran across something really interesting.  One of the events does not have a return value, but it calls variables from inside the function.  Prior knowledge tells me this should only work if the variables are global inside the function, yet the dispatcher is able to call the variables from outside the function.

**EDIT:  I just discovered that the variable that is accessed from inside the function needs to be one of the paramaters!  Could this be func_get_params() or call_user_func()?**

Calling Code:

```
$instance = JDispatcher::getInstance();
$instance->trigger(onJoomCalledEvent, array(&$link, $other_params));
```

Plugin (snippet):

```
class plgMyPlugin extends JPlugin{

    onJoomCalledEvent($link, $other_params){
        $link = "Some Value Here";
        return false;
    }
}
```

This function returns false, yet somehow the application (Joomla!) is able to extract the value of $link.  How is this done?

Comment: Can you post a link to the (full) code in question?

Comment: The actual code that does this is part of Joomla, specifically the JDisplatcher class.  The "Calling Code" I have added above is the code from the component that calls the plugin.

Comment: It looks like JDispatcher has been deprecated.  I think what they are trying to do is pass `$link` by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) so that any changes to it in the called function would also change the variable passed in.  The way it is being passed is deprecated in PHP 5.3.  The reference has to be declared in the function, and not when passing the value in at call time.

Comment: I just did some further reading on references, and you are correct.  What is happening is the component is declaring the $link variable, and by passing it as a reference to onJoomCalledEvent, it can be modified (or in this case set) by the plugin.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Where did you find that JDisplatcher has been deprecated?  It does not say so in the source code or online.

Comment: I cloned the repo from GitHub, here is the file for JDispatcher that is deprecated.  It will throw an exception when you try to use it.  https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/legacy/dispatcher/dispatcher.php  This appears to be the replacement: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/event/dispatcher.php  I'm not too familiar with Joomla so I'm not sure if what I'm looking at is current or future code.  Either way, the call-time pass-by-reference demonstrated in the code you posted is now deprecated behavior in PHP and will throw errors in PHP 5.3

Comment: Must be future code, either ways I have more work to do now.  Anyway, thanks so very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the plug-in definition look like this:

```
class plgMyPlugin extends JPlugin{

    onJoomCalledEvent(&$link, $other_params){
        $link = "Some Value Here";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Than it's [pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). If it's indeed the way you posted above than it's call time pass by reference which is deprecated and emits a warning starting with PHP 5.3.